# What is rpc and p2p code for Ethereum token? What to give as GitHub source code of an Ethereum token in exchange?

Tags: contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp, json-rpc, exchanges, devp2p

I’m new to Ethereum development. From ethereum token docs I came to know the process of deploying the token. But at some exchanges they ask for RPC and P2P port as well as the github source of the coin. I’ve searched everywhere almost. No direct answer. Maybe I’m a complete newbie but please give me a direction.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a contract you don't need anything apart from a synced node and an account with some ethers.

> But at some exchanges they ask for RPC and P2P port as well as the
>   github source of the coin.

I am not sure what exchanges are you talking about. Exchanges are made for trading only, they usually don't provide the facility of deploying a contract.

An exchange may ask for details like abi and address of contract when you try to register your coin at any exchange. They may also ask you gitHub repo of your contract. But for deployment, you don't need to worry about all this.

Comment: I'm talking about novaexchange and bittrex. They both ask for rpc, P2P port and github source repo. Thanks for replying.. if you can give me direction it will help a lot.

Comment: Will they accept contract repo for sure?

Comment: I am not sure on how bittrex works.Let me check.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to replicate your case? I didn't find a place on `bittrex` to deploy a smart contract at first sight. ARe to trying to deploy a smart contract on bittrex?